# INNER JOIN vs LEFT JOIN performance in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have this query in SQL and I would like to know which one
(LEFT JOIN / INNER JOIN) do I have to use in order to increase the speed and improve the proficiency

```
UPDATE poker_hands f
INNER JOIN (poker_cards a, poker_cards b, 
poker_cards c, poker_cards d,  poker_cards e)
ON f.r1 = a.card_name 
AND f.r2 = b.card_name
AND f.r3 = c.card_name
AND f.r4 = d.card_name
AND f.r5 = e.card_name
SET f.hand_type = 'Royal flush'
WHERE ((a.suit = b.suit AND b.suit = c.suit 
AND c.suit = d.suit AND d.suit = e.suit)
AND (a.game_value = 14 AND b.game_value = 13 
AND c.game_value = 12 AND d.game_value = 11 AND e.game_value = 10));
```

Comment: Which server? [mysql] or [sql-server]?

Comment: Try it with both and see which one runs faster. If you can't tell a difference, then you are wasting your time trying to optimize something that you're not even sure needs to be optimized. Also, those 2 things are not equivalent so the question is odd to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this statement, the predicates in the `WHERE` clause would negate the "outerness" of a LEFT JOIN, making equivalent to an INNER JOIN.

I'd expect the optimizer would recognize that, and choose the most cost efficient plan in either case. I'd expect equivalent execution plans, and I wouldn't expect to observe a performance difference in this query, when the `INNER` keyword is replaced with `LEFT`.

But without looking at the actual execution plans, that's just conjecture. To see the execution plan, we can use `EXPLAIN` (for MySQL) or `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON` (for SQL Server, or `STATISTICS PROFILE ON`, et al.)

The actual performance of the different statements can be observed and measured.

---

I'm not understanding why you would want to use a LEFT JOIN at all.

(And the mixing of the old-school comma syntax for the join operation with the newer JOIN keyword... what's up with that?)

---

As far as improving performance, we'd really need to make sure that suitable indexes are available, and are being used. We need to look at the execution plans. We may need to make sure that statistics are collected and up-to-date, and we may need to make some tweaks to the SQL to get an more efficient plan.

It's possible that replacing `INNER` with `LEFT` may make a difference in performance of the existing query, but it's unlikely to be a cure to a performance problem.

Personally, I'd prefer to investigate performance of an equivalent query, with this as a starting point:

```
UPDATE poker_hands f
  JOIN poker_cards a ON a.card_name = f.r1 AND a.game_value = 14
  JOIN poker_cards b ON b.card_name = f.r2 AND b.game_value = 13 AND b.suit = a.suit
  JOIN poker_cards c ON c.card_name = f.r3 AND c.game_value = 12 AND c.suit = a.suit
  JOIN poker_cards d ON d.card_name = f.r4 AND d.game_value = 11 AND d.suit = a.suit
  JOIN poker_cards e ON e.card_name = f.r5 AND e.game_value = 10 AND e.suit = a.suit
   SET f.hand_type = 'Royal flush'
```

Answer (score 1):

Performance is not the question-- `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` do different things.  Use whichever one fits your need